# 403 The request could not be satisfied response when hitting the Cowin API

Tags: php, amazon-cloudfront

403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied cowin API
getting above error while hitting the cowin API
This is working fine on local machine and post man
here is my code

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=512&date=16-05-2021%0A',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: 403 error looks like you are missing authentication. Please, edit your response and include which type of authentication are you using.

Comment: I am using this link
Get method https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=314&date=18-05-2021

Comment: I am trying to calling this APIs https://apisetu.gov.in/public/api/cowin